# R's predict() function object is not found

Tags: r, machine-learning

Im trying to pass in new data to the predict function , and the new data is partial only 3 of the 110+ columns are filled, Im getting the error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Cell' not found

although  column "Cell" is present, below is my R script:

```
library("AppliedPredictiveModeling")
library("ElemStatLearn")
library("pgmm")
library("rpart")
library("gtools")
library("caret")

# load data
data(segmentationOriginal)

# Subset the data to a training set and testing set based on
# the Case variable in the data set.

training <- segmentationOriginal[which(segmentationOriginal$Case == 
  "Train"), ]

testing <- segmentationOriginal[which(segmentationOriginal$Case == 
  "Test"), ]

# Set the seed to 125 and fit a CART model with the rpart
# method using all predictor variables and default caret
# settings.

set.seed(125)

modFit <- train(Class ~ ., method = "rpart", data = training)

modFit$finalModel

# use new values to predict , TotalIntench2 = 23,000;
# FiberWidthCh1 = 10; PerimStatusCh1=2

# create new data frame based on old data frame columns, this
# will contain new data
training1 <- training[0, ]

# create data frame with test values
newdata = data.frame(TotalIntench2 = 50000, FiberWidthCh1 = 10, 
  VarIntenCh4 = 100)

# use gtools package smartbind()
training1 <- training1[nrow(training1) + 1, ]
training1 <- smartbind(training1, newdata)

# remove initial empty row
training1[-c(1), ]

# inspect
training1[1, 0]

predict(modFit, newdata = training1[1, 0])
```

How can I pass new data with partial columns populated to the predict() function?

Thanks

Comment: Whats the reason for the down vote? I would like guidance on this problem.

Comment: what are you trying to do hear ? `training1 <- training1[nrow(training1) + 1, ] training1 <- smartbind(training1, newdata)` ?

Comment: Also, your `training1[1, 0]`, has no columns

Comment: Im trying to pass 'newdata = data.frame(TotalIntench2 = 50000, FiberWidthCh1 = 10, 
  VarIntenCh4 = 100)' to predict()

Comment: Without see what the data or what the model looks likes, it is just guess here.  Are you sure your newly created data matches your model?

Comment: This is nonsense: `predict(modFit, newdata = training1[1, 0])`. You pass a data.frame without columns and are surprised when `predict` can't find anything in it?

Comment: There are several issues with this question:

1. The 5 steps to create `training1` simply don't make sense. Can you explain what form you expect it to take? There's certainly a better way.

2. As far as I can tell, your model uses all 119 variables, so you need to provide all 119 variables in `newdata` as well. If you want to predict on 3 variables, fit a new model passing just those three columns to `train()`.

3. As @Roland points out, `training1[1, 0]` is a dataframe with no columns! You're not actually passing any data to `predict`. Read `help('[')` to learn proper subsetting in R.

Comment: Wow, the attitude on this forum , sorry I had a bug, that why I posted the question, if there wasnt a bug, why would I ask for help.

Comment: In many programming languages array[0] refers to the first element, while in R, array[1] is the first element. Could this be the source of confusion?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, in general for rpart, you cannot transfer partial columns predict. if you have no data for some of the columns, set them as NAs and and pass those columns to the dataframe (newdata).

simply apply the below command with right data.

predict(modFit, newdata )